# Flutter: Correct way to import external list

Tags: flutter

While my current code works, I just want to make sure I'm doing it correctly (or if there is a better way).

If I want to store a list in a separate file to be used in a Listview or Gridview, is this the correct way to do it?

**1. Create a model (menu.dart)**

```
class MenuModel {
  MenuModel(
    this.title,
    this.icon,
   );

 final String title;
 final Icon icon;
}
```

**2. Create a Menu List (menu_list.dart)**

```
class MenuList{
  final List<MenuModel> menuList= [
    MenuModel("Link 1", Icon(Icons.menu)),
    MenuModel("Link 2", Icon(Icons.nature)),
  ];
}
```

**3. Import it (my_page.dart)**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  List _menuList= MenuList().menuList;
...

GridView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  itemCount: _menuList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return GridCard(
      title: _menuList[index].title,
      icon: _menuList[index].icon,
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: If the list of menu are static values, then your current implementation is fine.